# symfony batch only first flush is working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my code below. Only the first flush() is working. Subsequent flushes are being reached and called, but having no effect.

If I remove the flush() and clear() from the loop, all records are updated (but I need to limit the search to prevent memory issues).

```
$processedEntries = 0;

$advertQuery = $entityManager->createQuery(
    "SELECT a
       FROM MyBundle:Advert a
       LEFT JOIN MyBundle:History prh
      WHERE prh.id IS NULL"
);

$advertQuery->setFirstResult(0);
$advertResults = $advertQuery->getResult();

foreach ($advertResults as $advertEntity) {
    $advertEntity->setTimeModified(new \DateTime());

    try {
        $processedEntries++;

        if (($processedEntries % self::COMMIT_BATCH_SIZE) === 0) {
            $entityManager->flush(); // Executes all updates.
            $entityManager->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
        }

    } catch(\Exception $ex) {

        $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->resetEntityManager();
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}

$entityManager->flush(); // Executes all updates.
```

Comment: After the first `clear` the remaining `$advertEntity` are no longer managed. As you don't use `persist` I'd guess you are using event handlers. So I'd say doctrine is not calling these handlers for unmanged entities. Simplest solution might be to just call `$entityManager->persist($advertEntity);`.

Comment: As Yoshi said, you remove your queryResult by calling $entityManager->clear(). What about $entityManager->detach($advertEntity); and unset($advertEntity); this should work as expected.